# Flask-Restful: can't parse args of json nested value

Tags: flask-restful, flask-restplus

I've got the json

```
{
    "message":  {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar"
    }
}
```

And parser:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
parser.add_argument('foo', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('bar', type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And the error is :
{'foo': 'Missing required parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string', 'bar': 'Missing required parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string'}

Answer (score 2):

Since your `'foo'` and `'bar'` keys are inside `'message'`, the JSON parsing has to start from '`message`'. 
ie. You have to let know the parser about `'message'` before you can parse `'foo'` from it.

For this, you have to set up a root parser which parses your `'message'`. You can do this in the following way:

```
root_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
root_parser.add_argument('message', type=dict)
root_args = root_parser.parse_args()

message_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
message_parser.add_argument('foo', type=dict, location=('message',))
message_parser = message_parser.parse_args(req=root_args)
```

For more info please take a look at the [issue from github](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/517)